# How can I create a smart group with no matching contacts?

Tags: contacts, groups, smartgroups

Is there a way via the UI to create a smart group with no matching contacts in the database? For example, our database does not currently have any contacts where the city is "Cottonwood," but I'd like to create a smart group for Cottonwood residents now so when someone with a Cottonwood address is added, they're automatically added to that group.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The easiest way would be to create a test contact with city Cottonwood, search on it. Create a smart search out of it and then delete the test contact.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I'd been hoping there was a more graceful way than this, but it's not too bad.

Comment: I agree. On the other hand: You would want to test your search anyway, making sure you did not make a typo or so.